# How to use Vue mixins correctly

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working with VueJS (as part of Laravel) since a few days now and i want to re-use code for e.g.  making API calls. I found on Google that "Mixins" are the way to go as it is a no go to use native ES6 classes. I'm familiair with javascript mixin's but cant get it working on the Vue way.

I found multiple implementations on Google and tried them but i cant get it working. Maybe i understand something wrong?

app.js

```
...
import appSettingStore from "./stores/appSettingStore";
...
export const eventBus = new Vue();
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    appSettingStore,
    // apiHelper,
    // data() {
    //     return {
    //         data: {
    //             testData: "",
    //             store: appSettingStore,
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
});
...
```

appSettingStore.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import apiHelper from '../apiHelper';   // tried with and without this line
Vue.use(Vuex);
...
const appSettingStore = new Vuex.Store({
    mixins: [apiHelper],   
    state: {
        accounts: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        setAccounts(state, accounts) {
            // some mutation logic
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getAccounts({commit}) {
            // Here i want to call the mixin method, tried something like:
            // this.getRequest(x,y,z);
            // apiHelper.getRequest(x,y,z);
            // getRequest(x,y,z);
        }
    }
});

export default appSettingStore;
```

apiHelper.js

```
const apiHelper = Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        getRequest(url, headers, body) {
            let subDomain = window.location.host.split('.')[0];
            let baseUrl = `http://${subDomain}.festipay.xlan/api/v1`;
            let header = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}

            axios.get(baseUrl + "url", header)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    return error;
                });
        }
    }
});
export default apiHelper;
```

The action `getAccounts` is "called" from another vue componenten (tested with console.log()).

The error i have in devtools console is `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getRequest is not a function"`

How can i solve this error/issue?
When more information i required, just let me know and i will update my post.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the declaration of the mixin and use a regular JavaScript method?
Example, instead of:
const apiHelper = Vue.mixin({

Use: 
const apiHelper = () => {...

Comment: Thanks, i can call the function of the mixin now. I changed it to a regular JS method as you suggested, removed the `method: {}` tag arround the `getRequest` and changed the place where i added the `mixins: []`. Console.log shows me the method is executed but the `comit` function does not work if it is inside the mixin JS method. I gues it is because the method is outside the Vue ecosystem now (As it is not a Vue class)

Comment: Nice, I'm glad that it's working now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the people who wants to achieve the same, an example how i did it. I used this way in a Laravel 6 application so i'm not sure if it works in other projects/frameworks or stand alone.

My api helper:

```
let apiHelper = {
  getRequest(url, callback) {
    console.log ("you hit the apiHelper getRequest function")
    let baseUrl = `http://${subDomain}.festipay.xlan/api/v1`;
    let header = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}


    axios.get(baseUrl + url, header)
      .then(function (response) {
        callback(response.data.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // do something with the error...
      });
  },
}
export default apiHelper;
```

a (stripped) copy of my vuex store component:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import apiHelper from '../apiHelper';   // import the helper class here

Vue.use(Vuex);

const appSettingStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        accounts: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        setAccounts(state, accounts) {
            state.accounts = accounts;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getAccounts({commit}) {
            apiHelper.getRequest("/app_settings", (data) => {commit('setAccounts', data)});      // just call the method like this, note that you need to use a callback function to receive the result!
          });
        },
    }
});

export default appSettingStore;
```